# Cordova plugin background-geolocation-lt results in undefined error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

The Ionic 2 project is a TypeScript project.

I installed `cordova-background-geolocation-lt` with

```
ionic plugin add cordova-background-geolocation-lt
```

and tried to implement it as a replacement for the older `cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation` plugin, but I kept getting variations of the following error.

```
10    275176   group    EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: window.BackgroundGeolocation is undefined
```

The plugin's config states that it clobbers window.BackgroundGeolocation.

I get the error even if I access it in the constructor of app.ts

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    StatusBar.styleDefault();

    window.BackgroundGeolocation.onMotionchange(
        (isMoving) => {
            console.log('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation::onMotionChange: ', isMoving);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation::onMotionChange error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
});
```

ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.3
```

ionic plugin list:

```
com.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation 1.5.1 "BackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-dantelo-phonestate 0.0.1 "PhoneState"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.0.1 "Keyboard"
```

**Update: To reproduce the error in a few steps.**

I created a new project with

```
ionic start Test blank --v2 --ts
cd Test
ionic plugin add https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt.git
ionic platform add android
```

The last line adds any dependencies `cordova-background-geolocation-lt` has.

I then modified app.ts by adding

```
declare var window:any;
```

after the imports, and

```
window.BackgroundGeolocation.onMotionchange(
    (isMoving) => {
        console.log('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation::onMotionChange: ', isMoving);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation::onMotionChange error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

to the constructor, as seen above.

Running `ionic serve -l -c -s` will then fail with the `undefined` error mentioned above.

Comment: You tried this on android or iOS ? As far as I know this is a paid plugin right?

Comment: I had at that point only tried this on the browser. I managed to test on iOS, the target platform, and it seems to work though. But I'd love for the browser to work with `ionic serve` as well.

Comment: You cant use it in browser because the plugin is using native stuff that doesnt exist on the phone. The plugin is calling Java/Objective C in background to call the GPS, Camera... In browser these things do not exist

Comment: I know that, but as the plug-in defines its use of `window.BackgroundGeolocation` in its plugin.xml, the variable should at least be defined.